# Customising Bootstrap grid to 60 columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What are the downsides of customising a Bootstrap grid to 60 columns? From what I have gathered in forums people say that it is hard to manage. I take that onboard by as long as you keep to 5, 10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 30, 60 it does remain fairly simple and gives you a huge flexibility of splitting up your page.

- 60 = 1/1
- 30 = 1/2
- 20 = 1/3
- 15 = 1/4
- 12 = 1/5
- 10 = 1/6
- 6 = 1/10
- 5 = 1/12
- 4 = 1/15
- 3 = 1/20

This gives me more flexibility crucially allowing 1/5.
Could there be significant stress for the CPU for rendering the extra css? what other down sides are there?

Comment: you can always develop it, create your own CSS framework and share it ;) ... i would say that for bootstrap it's a choice and a decision that was enough good